# Prove algebraically $\vec{x} = \vec{a} + s\vec{b}, s\in \mathbb R$ and $\vec{x} = \vec{c} + t\vec{d}, t\in \mathbb R$ intersect

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, vectors

> Given two lines $\vec{x} = \vec{a} + s\vec{b}, s\in \mathbb R$ and  $\vec{x} = \vec{c} + t\vec{d}, t\in \mathbb R$ in $\mathbb R^2$, where $\vec{d} \not= k\vec{b}, k\in \mathbb R$, prove algebraically these two lines intersect.

I know logically that this is true since if two lines are not parallel then they must intersect eventually, but how do I show this algebraically?

Comment: I’d like to point out that $\vec x$ is not a line; however, $$\bigcup_{s\in\Bbb R}\left\{ (h,k): \vec{x}=\pmatrix{h\\k}\right\}$$ is a locus in the form of a line. There is a subtle difference between the two.

Comment: Actually, unless of course you define an ordered point as equivalent to a vector. I realize that many fields do this to simplify notation, like $f(x,y,z)=f(\mathbf{r})$.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need the vectors being in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

As $\vec{d}\ne k\vec{b}$ $\forall k\in\mathbb{R}$, $\vec{b}$ and $\vec{d}$ are linearly independent.

So, there exist non-zero numbers $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\vec{a}-\vec{c}=\alpha\vec{b}+\beta\vec{d}$.

Here $\vec{a}+(-\alpha)\vec{b}=\vec{c}+\beta\vec{d}$ lies on both lines and is the point of intersection of the lines.